# git rev-parse --git-path hooks always return absolute path

Tags: git, bash, shell, git-submodules, githooks

Is there an equivalent command to this that always returns the absolute path?

```
git rev-parse --git-path hooks
```

When I'm in a submodule, I get an absolute path, but when I'm in the root repository, I get

> .git/hooks

Comment: The usual way to flesh out an arbitrary path is with `readlink`, ```path=$(readlink -e "`git rev-parse --git-path hooks`")``` should do it.  If you wanted to cook up an `--absolute-git-path` like the `--absolute-git-dir` rev-parse arg I'd think a good patch would be accepted,

Comment: I was trying `--absolute-git-dir` but having some problems. It would just print out `--absolute-git-dir` when I ran `git rev-parse --absolute-git-dir`. Any idea why? But the `readlink` solution does seem to work, thanks!

Comment: It's a brand-new option, added in 2.13. btw, I think `readlink -nf` would be  better than the `readlink -e` I showed above.

Comment: With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), you will have `git rev-parse --path-format=absolute --git-path hooks`. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65756847/6309).

Answer (score 4):

Git v2.13.0 has `--absolute-git-dir`:

```
$ git rev-parse --absolute-git-dir
/Users/torek/...snip.../.git
```

but not `--absolute-git-path`, and as you note, `--git-path` produces a relative result:

```
$ git rev-parse --git-path hooks
.git/hooks
```

If you *do* have Git 2.13, though, you can combine these using the sh/bash environment variable prefix method:

```
$ GIT_DIR=$(git rev-parse --absolute-git-dir) git rev-parse --git-path hooks
/Users/torek/...[snip].../.git/hooks
```

If not—if your Git is older than 2.13—you can use `readlink -f`:

```
$ GIT_DIR=$(readlink -f $(git rev-parse --git-dir)) git rev-parse --git-path hooks
/home/vagrant/...snip.../.git/hooks
```

(in a certain Linux image on my laptop; this particular Linux image has Git 2.7.4 installed).

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), "[`git rev-parse`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9ba366f12baa9eae07c07fad0e873940dfc25e11/Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse))</sup> can be explicitly told to give output as absolute or relative path with the `--path-format=(absolute|relative)` option.

So if you want to be *sure* and have an absolute path:

```
git rev-parse --path-format=absolute --git-path hooks
```

See [commit fac60b8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fac60b89252e5865da077bb6ccaa9bef43efbfeb), [commit be6e0da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be6e0daee700b2ee28846b54ddfefe08cd4ec506) (13 Dec 2020) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9ba366f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ba366f12baa9eae07c07fad0e873940dfc25e11), 15 Jan 2021)</sup>

> ### [`rev-parse`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fac60b89252e5865da077bb6ccaa9bef43efbfeb): add option for absolute or relative path formatting
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>

> [`git rev-parse`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fac60b89252e5865da077bb6ccaa9bef43efbfeb/Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse))</sup> has several options which print various paths.
> Some of these paths are printed relative to the current working directory, and some are absolute.
>
> Normally, this is not a problem, but there are times when one wants paths entirely in one format or another.
> This can be done trivially if the paths are canonical, but canonicalizing paths is not possible on some shell scripting environments which lack [`realpath(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/realpath.1.html) and also in Go, which lacks functions that properly canonicalize paths on Windows.
>
> To help out the scripter, let's provide an option which turns most of the paths printed by `git rev-parse` to be either relative to the current working directory or absolute and canonical.
> Document which options are affected and which are not so that users are not confused.
>
> This approach is cleaner and tidier than providing duplicates of existing options which are either relative or absolute.
>
> Note that if the user needs both forms, it is possible to pass an additional option in the middle of the command line which changes the behavior of subsequent operations.

`git rev-parse` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fac60b89252e5865da077bb6ccaa9bef43efbfeb/Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt#L215-L226):

> ### `--path-format=(absolute|relative)`
>
> Controls the behavior of certain other options.
>
> - If specified as absolute, the paths printed by those options will be absolute and canonical.
> - If specified as relative, the paths will be relative to the current working directory if that is possible.
>   The default is option specific.
>
> This option may be specified multiple times and affects only the arguments that
> follow it on the command line, either to the end of the command line or the next
> instance of this option.
>
> The following options are modified by `--path-format`:

`git rev-parse` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fac60b89252e5865da077bb6ccaa9bef43efbfeb/Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt#L253-L254):

> ### `--show-toplevel`
>
> Show the (by default, absolute) path of the top-level directory
> of the working tree.
> If there is no working tree, report an error.

`git rev-parse` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fac60b89252e5865da077bb6ccaa9bef43efbfeb/Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt#L266-L295):

> The following options are unaffected by `--path-format`:
>
> ### `--absolute-git-dir`
>
> Like `--git-dir`, but its output is always the canonicalized
> absolute path.
>
> ### `--is-inside-git-dir`
>
> When the current working directory is below the repository
> directory print "true", otherwise "false".
>
> ### `--is-inside-work-tree`
>
> When the current working directory is inside the work tree of the
> repository print "true", otherwise "false".
>
> ### `--is-bare-repository`
>
> When the repository is bare print "true", otherwise "false".
>
> ### `--is-shallow-repository`
>
> When the repository is shallow print "true", otherwise "false".
>
> ### `--show-cdup`
>
> When the command is invoked from a subdirectory, show the
> path of the top-level directory relative to the current
> directory (typically a sequence of "../", or an empty string).
>
> ### `--show-prefix`
>
> When the command is invoked from a subdirectory, show the
> path of the current directory relative to the top-level
> directory.

---

Warning: The "`rev-parse`" command did not diagnose the lack of argument to "`--path-format`" option, which was introduced in v2.31 era: that has been corrected with Git 2.32 (Q2 2021).

See [commit 99fc555](https://github.com/git/git/commit/99fc555188681caeedc983b9fc982d6dc8ee2a8c) (17 May 2021) by [Wolfgang Müller (`wylfen`)](https://github.com/wylfen).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 99fe1c6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/99fe1c606925ecd427af6e0338ec18936407ba48), 22 May 2021)</sup>

> ### [`rev-parse`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/99fc555188681caeedc983b9fc982d6dc8ee2a8c): fix segfault with missing `--path-format` argument
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Wolfgang Müller</sup>

> Calling "[`git rev-parse --path-format`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/99fc555188681caeedc983b9fc982d6dc8ee2a8c/Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt#L215)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt---path-format(absolute%7Crelative)))</sup> without an argument segfaults instead of giving an error message.
> Commit [fac60b8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fac60b89252e5865da077bb6ccaa9bef43efbfeb) ("`rev-parse`: add option for absolute or relative path formatting", 2020-12-13, Git v2.31.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ba366f12baa9eae07c07fad0e873940dfc25e11) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4151fdb1c76c1a190ac9241b67223efd19f3e478)) added the argument parsing code but forgot to handle `NULL`.
>
> Returning an error makes sense here because there is no default value we could use.
> Add a test case to verify.

The error message will now accurately be:

```
fatal: --path-format requires an argument
```